# Finding an orthogonal matrix P such that $P^tAP$ is diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm near the end of the question, and I've become very frustrated after struggling to find my mistake for hours.

The question is regarding this matrix, and finding an orthogonal diagonalisation for it

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b & b \\
b & a & b \\
b & b & a \\
\end{bmatrix} $

Thus far I have worked out the eigenvalues of the matrix to be $(a-b)$ (multiplicity 2) and $(a-4b)$ (multiplicity 1). Corresponding to $(a-b)$, a bases to its eigenspace are $(1,0,-1)$, and $(0,1,-1)$. Corresponding to $(a-4b)$, a bases to its eigenspace is $(1,1,1)$.

Now comes the frustrating part: I've found an orthonormal bases for the vector space in terms of the eigenvalues of the matrix A to be $(1/\sqrt3)(1,1,1), (1/\sqrt2)(1,0,-1), (1/\sqrt3)(-1,1,-1)$, but to my dismay, I cannot seem to arrange them into a symmetric matrix! This has been driving me crazy for hours, and I'd be grateful if someone could point out my mistake.

Comment: Why do you want to put the eigenvalues into a symmetric matrix?  The question asks you to find an orthogonal matrix.  Do you understand what "orthogonal" and "symmetric" mean?

Comment: How is that an orthonormal basis? The first basis vector is not orthogonal to the third one. And why did you need to find the eigenvalues in the first place? Since $A=(a-b)I+3buu^T$, where $u=\frac1{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)^T$, all you need is to find a real orthogonal matrix $Q$ whose first column is $u$, so that $Q^Tu=(1,0,0)^T$ and $Q^TAQ$ is diagonal.

Comment: @Brian Borchers Ah, I can't believe I made this blunder! I saw the transpose in the question and assumed, for some reason, that the matrix needed to be symmetric also! Thank you very much for pointing this out, seems like the frustration was for nothing after all. (I do understand what orthogonal (=> $P^tP = I$ and symmetric means)

Comment: Your eigenvalues are incorrect. They should add up to $3a$.

Comment: @amd Hi, I trust that you are probably correct, but could you please tell me the reason why that is the case?

Comment: The sum of the eigenvalues, taking multiplicity into account, is equal to the trace of the matrix. The latter is $3a$, but your eigenvalues add up to $3a-6b$. It’s easy to see which one’s wrong: multiplying by $(1,1,1)^T$ is the same as adding across the rows, but the row sums of $A$ are $a+2b$, not $a-4b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
P = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} & \frac{-1}{\sqrt 2} & \frac{-1}{\sqrt 6} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} & \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & \frac{-1}{\sqrt 6} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} & 0 & \frac{2}{\sqrt 6}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Below is a matrix $P$ that I made up some time ago.  Note that this $P$ is not orthogonal, although the columns are pairwise orthogonal. The columns are eigenvectors of the matrix with all entries equal to $1.$ Suppose we call $J$ the square  matrix with all entries equal to $1.$ The matrix in the original question is $(a-b)I + b J.$ This has different eigenvalues but the same eigenvectors as $J.$   The eigenvalues of $J$ are $(n,0,0,0,0...,0).$ The eigenvalues of $bJ$ are $(nb,0,0,0,0...,0).$
The eigenvalues of $(a-b)I + b J$ are $(a+(n-1)b,a-b,a-b,a-b,a-b...,a-b);$ note that this sum is $na,$ the correct trace.
$$    
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  2  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  3  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  4  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  5  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  6  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  7  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  8  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  9   
\end{array}
  \right).
  $$

The columns of $P$ are of varying lengths; for the 10 by 10 case depicted, lengths $ \sqrt{10}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{6}, \sqrt{12},..$ All that is necessary to make an orthogonal matrix $Q$ out of this is to divide each column by its length. In turn, this tells us that $\det P = \pm n!,$ as $\det Q = \pm 1.$ The result is $Q^T Q = Q Q^T = I$ and $Q^T = Q^{-1}.$ Meanwhile, $Q^T A Q= Q^{-1}AQ$ is diagonal, in this case the diagonal elements are the eigenvalues.